# How can I display significant stars using Zelig package

Tags: r, regression, non-linear-regression, r-zelig

I'd like to display significant stars in the result of Zelig regression with robust Standard Errors for tobit model.
Code is like this. But there are no significant stars, like normal tobit regression using AER package(tobit command)

```
library(Zelig)
# input
dat <- read.csv("http://www.omori.e.u-tokyo.ac.jp/STATA/Sample/select.csv")
head(dat)

# robust tobit
rb.tobit <- zelig(HOUR~CHILD+AGE+EDU+WAGE+HINC, below=0, above=Inf, model="tobit", data=dat, robust=T)
summary(rb.tobit)
```

```
Model: 

Call:
z5$zelig(formula = HOUR ~ CHILD + AGE + EDU + WAGE + HINC, below = 0, 
    above = Inf, robust = T, data = dat)

Observations:
         Total  Left-censored     Uncensored Right-censored 
           753            325            428              0 

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept) 1130.70774  443.05762   2.552  0.01071
CHILD       -806.15058  245.32541  -3.286  0.00102
AGE          -24.10593    7.68759  -3.136  0.00171
EDU           22.86477   31.14134   0.734  0.46281
WAGE         201.39910   34.23250   5.883 4.02e-09
HINC         -53.92795   23.04316  -2.340  0.01927
Log(scale)     7.04989    0.04425 159.316  < 2e-16

Scale: 1153 

Gaussian distribution
Number of Newton-Raphson Iterations: 4 
Log-likelihood: -3812 on 7 Df
Wald-statistic: 75.14 on 5 Df, p-value: 8.6858e-15 

Next step: Use 'setx' method
```

No stars in the right of the Coefficients.

Is there anyone know how to display significant stars?

Answer (score 2):

even if it is a Little late:

-> type in: summary(rb.tobit, **signif.stars=TRUE**)
then it should work.